# Problem getting complete .pem from ansible letsencrypt / acme_certificate module

Tags: ssl, ansible, lets-encrypt

I was using Ansible 2.4 and included the letsencrypt module in one of my roles hoping to get a complete `.pem' format file at the end (key, chain, cert).  There was no problem generating the key or using the csr to request the new cert, and no problem with the challenge, but when everything was done, I was only getting the certificate back, no chain.

When I tried to use them, Apache would fail to start saying that the key and the cert did not match.  I assumed that this was because I didn't include the chain which was missing.

According to the docs here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/acme_certificate_module.html the `chain|chain_dest` and `fullchain|fullchain_dest` parameters weren't added until Ansible 2.5.  So I upgraded to Ansible 2.7 (via git), and I'm still running into the exact same error...

```
FAILED! => {
  "changed": false, 
  "msg": "
    Unsupported parameters for (letsencrypt) module: chain_dest, fullchain_dest 
    Supported parameters include: account_email, account_key, acme_directory, agreement, 
    challenge, csr, data, dest, remaining_days"
}
```

I've tried the aliases and current names for both but nothing is working.  Here is my current challenge-response call:

```
- name: Let the challenge be validated and retrieve the cert and intermediate certificate
  letsencrypt:
    account_key: /etc/ssl/lets_encrypt.key
    account_email: #####@#####.###
    csr: /etc/ssl/{{ myhost.public_hostname }}.csr
    dest: /etc/ssl/{{ myhost.public_hostname }}.crt
    chain_dest: /etc/ssl/{{ myhost.public_hostname }}.int
    fullchain_dest: /etc/ssl/{{ myhost.public_hostname }}.pem
    challenge: dns-01
    acme_directory: https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    remaining_days: 60
    data: "{{ le_com_challenge }}"
  tags: sslcert
```

The documentation says that this is valid, but the error response does not include `chain|chain_dest` or `fullchain|fullchain_dest` as valid parameters.

I would, from the docs, expect that this response should result in the new certificate being created (.crt), the chain being created (.int), and the fullchain to be created (.pem).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have waited 5 minutes... seems that the newer parameters are only available under the newer module name `acme_certificate`, even though it says `letsencrypt` was a valid alias.  As soon as I updated this it worked.